# UML mapping with c#

Tags: c#, class-design, uml, class-diagram

There are two classes Person and Employee [image]

when it mapped to c# code

```
public class Person
{
    private string Name;
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    private string Department;

    public string GetName()
    {
        return "Person Name";
    }
}
```

My question is where can i write the getters and setters for this private attributes.is it ok to write them with in the same Person and Employee classes if yes isn't there a problem with mapping? because methods are also with in the same class(GetName()) or do i have to use separate classes for writing getters and setters.i'm confused with this class diagram mapping with the code.Can any one resolve this for me??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would recommend you to you the *properties* approach and not the *getters / setters* one.

My take:

```
public class Person {

    private string name;

    public string Name {
        get {
            return this.name;
        }
    }
}

public class Department {

    private int id;
    private string name;

    public int ID {
        get {
            return this.id;
        }
    }

    public string Name {
        get {
            return this.name;
        }
    }
}

public class Employee : Person {

    private Department department;

    public Department Department {
        get {
            return this.department;
        }
    }
}
```

`Employee.Name` returns the employee name which is being declared within the Person class.

Comment: Can i do the same for Department in Employee class?